# html5 + phaser issues

Tags: html, intel-xdk, phaser-framework

I'm trying to develop a game using xdk with Phaser library. I have 2 prefabs and I have error in them.

Here is the code of one of them and the html of the game:

```js
var BasicGame = BasicGame || {};
BasicGame.balls = function(game ,x,y ) {

Phaser.Sprite.call(this,game,x,y);
this.game=game;
this.game.physics.Arcade.enable(this) ;
this.anchor.setTo(0.5) ; 
    this.body.velocity = this.game.RandomDataGenerator ;
};
BasicGame.balls.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
BasicGame.balls.prototype.constructor = BasicGame.balls ;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Phaser Full Screen Mobile Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1, IE=9">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Phaser App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=0 minimal-ui" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- non-retina iPhone pre iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/app_icon_57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/app_icon_60x60.png">
    <!-- non-retina iPad pre iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/app_icon_72x72.png">
    <!-- non-retina iPad iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/app_icon_76x76.png">
    <!-- retina iPhone pre iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/app_icon_114x114.png">
    <!-- retina iPhone iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/app_icon_120x120.png">
    <!-- retina iPad pre iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/app_icon_144x144.png">
    <!-- retina iPad iOS 7 -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/app_icon_152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="icons/app_icon_256x256.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icons/app_icon_512x512.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="1024x1024" href="icons/app_icon_1024x1024.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Load Phaser engine -->
    <script src="lib/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load game source files -->
    <script src="src/Game.js"></script>
    <!-- Load game entrance -->
    <script src="src/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Load and initialize Cordova -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="src/cordova-init.js"></script>
    <script src="src/prefabs/balls.js"></script>
    <script src="src/prefabs/homes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main canvas for rendering game stage -->
    <div id="game"></div>
<div id="balls"></div>
<div id="homes"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is I have an error in the prefabs where 'Phaser' is not defined.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JSHint will report an error because it's only looking at a single file and can't know if some globals were defined elsewhere, as is the case with `Phaser`.  If you look in `www/src/app.js` you'll see a line like this:

```
/* globals Phaser:false, BasicGame: false */
```

This is a `JSHint` directive that tells it not to flag `Phaser` or `BasicGame` as undefined, i.e. assume they're globals defined elsewhere.

In any case, it shouldn't affect the running of your app.  You should see it defined in the debugger and in your running code.